# Laravel Nova routing from web.php file to the api.php route file within nova

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing a project of my own and I made a login script (with the standard auth from laravel). I added the 2fa Google Authenticator to the script on the normal Laravel installation (so not in the Nova folder). https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-add-googles-two-factor-authentication-to-laravel is the link to the tutorial i used.

I was wondering how I could link my registration and login that I get redirected to my /nova route dashboard

I have been trying for hours now but nothing seems to work since you cannot just give in a blade file reference since Laravel does not check into the Nova view folder but instead prefers the normal views folder

Some help would be greatly appreciated with an example or anything that could help me further my project

Thanks in advance!